# Limit of a sequence ratio with one defined recursively

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is a question from a calculus exam I recently failed, and I'd love some help with it:

Let $a_n$ be a sequence defined as following: $a_1=1$, and $\forall n>1: a_{n+1}=2^{a_n}$. Prove that $\frac{2^{n^K}}{a_n}\rightarrow0$ for any $K\ge1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

$$n^K\ll2^n$$

and

$$a_{n-3}>n\implies a_{n-2}>2^n\implies a_{n-1}>2^{2^n}\implies a_n>2^{2^{2^n}}$$

It's enough to verify that $a_4>7$ and that

$$a_{n-3}>n\implies a_{n-2}>2^n>n+1$$

which concludes the initial condition for the other induction hypothesis.

Thus,

$$a_n\gg2^{2^{2^n}}\gg2^{2^n}\gg2^{n^K}$$

Comment: Can you please explain how you got that $a_{n-3}>n$?

Comment: @Noa Since $a_{7-3}>7$ and$$a_{n-3}>n\implies a_{n-2}>2^n>n+1$$it is shown by induction that it holds for $n\ge7$.

Comment: Awesome! I finished the whole proof and it works. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem! :-)